# r - Dplyr 'ungroup' function in pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, group-by, dplyr

Imagine you have in R this 'dplyr' code:

```
test <- data %>%
        group_by(PrimaryAccountReference) %>% 
        mutate(Counter_PrimaryAccountReference = n()) %>% 
        ungroup()
```

how can I exactly convert this to pandas equivalent code ?
Shortly, I need to group by to add another column and then ungroup the initial query. My concern is about how to do 'ungroup' function using pandas package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you are able to do it with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
from datar import f
from datar.dplyr import group_by, mutate, ungroup, n

test = data >> \
       group_by(f.PrimaryAccountReference) >> \
       mutate(Counter_PrimaryAccountReference = n()) >> \
       ungroup()
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pandas way should be by using `transform` function:

```
data['Counter_PrimaryAccountReference'] = data.groupby('PrimaryAccountReference')['PrimaryAccountReference'].transform('size')
```

Comment: This is in no way equivalent to the dplyr code. The dplyr code allows you to assign multiple values from multiple columns.